# Difference between 'How ... enjoying the job'/'How ... getting on with your job'

Tags: meaning, difference

Is there a difference in meaning between these two sentences?

> How are you enjoying the job so far?

> How are you getting on with your job?

Answer (score 6):

The first question is asking how you feel about the job. For example: are you enjoying it, or are you unhappy with it?

The second question is asking how you are doing with your job. For example: are you having trouble with work, or are you making good progress?

Comment: Got it!! Thank you very much